# How to create multiple relations between the same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, models

I have a User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

and I have a Project model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Obviously right now each project is owned by a user and there can only be one user per project.  I now want to make my models represent another relation between the two models.  I want a User to be able to follow multiple Projects, no matter who owns the Project.  I know that I am going to have to use a has_many :through and create a join, but I cant wrap my head around how to change the model to keep my current relationship and add the new relationship.

Comment: When you say "follow multiple projects" do you mean users have read-only access to projects they dont own?

Comment: I want a User to be able to view a read-only listing of the projects they are interested in viewing, unless of course they own the project.  In that case,they still would be able to edit the project.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in that case, in your show/index action display all the projects (`Project.all`) in your project table.  This way all users have access to all the projects.  Now, in your edit action, use `user.projects.all` to display projects of that particular user.  That should solve your problem, I don't see the need of any further association here.

**Update:** 
This should suffice:

`class Project < ActiveRecord::Base`
`belongs_to :user`

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base`
`has_many :projects_followed, :through => :projects`
`user has_many :projects_owned, :through => :projects`

If you don't wish to create two more relations, create just one:
`class ProjectsSubscribed`

`belongs_to :project` 
with three fields: **project_id, is_owned, is_followed**

Comment: The User has 2 different relations with the projects.  He can be an owner or he can be a follower.

Answer (score 0):

Try following relation.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followers
  has_many :projects, :through => :followers
end

class Follower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followers
  has_many :users, :through => :followers
end
```

Note it:
You can use **has_many :through** relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don’t need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: What about the original relationship that where a single User has many Projects and a Project can only have 1 User?  That doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: You can use another model **projects_owned** to maintain old relation. it having project_id and user_id(means belongs_to relation). user have has_many to project_owned and project having has_one to project_owned.